# Does web2py support creating triggers in the database

Tags: mysql, database, python-2.7, triggers, web2py

Just wanted to know if it is possible to create database triggers in a MySQL database using web2py's DAL? If not what alternatives are available?

I need some way of linking back to some python code from a trigger that happens in MySQL.

Thanks in advance,
nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web2py DAL does not have specific syntax for creating triggers, but you can execute any SQL statements via `db.executesql()`. As an alternative, the web2py DAL includes its own [before and after callbacks](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#before-and-after-callbacks), which will work across different database backends.